# `region 'RAM' overflowed` error when using lvgl for a Zephyr project

Tags: nrf52, zephyr-rtos, lvgl

I am getting `region 'RAM' overflowed` errors when building a Zephyr project using lvgl 8.3 using nRF Connect for VS Code add-in. I see a lot of references to lvgl when building, such as:

```
[352/429] Building C object modules/lvgl/CMakeFiles/..__modules__lib__gui__lvgl__zephyr.dir/opt/nordic/ncs/v2.3.0/modules/lib/gui/lvgl/src/extra/widgets/calendar/lv_calendar.c.obj
```

Even when I added this to the prj.conf it still shows up in the terminal:

```
CONFIG_LV_USE_CALENDAR=n
```

There does not seem to be much documentation on Zephyr and lvgl, but the prj.conf appears to have some settings which I assume are to control which components are used. When I changed the default font in it, the font changed on my screen.

```
CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_28=y
```

Here are all of my configuration settings:

```
# nothing here
CONFIG_LV_Z_MEM_POOL_NUMBER_BLOCKS=8
CONFIG_MAIN_STACK_SIZE=2048
#CONFIG_SYSTEM_WORKQUEUE_STACK_SIZE=2048


# Display
CONFIG_SPI=y
CONFIG_DISPLAY=y
CONFIG_ST7789V=y
CONFIG_ST7789V_RGB565=y
CONFIG_DISPLAY_LOG_LEVEL_ERR=y

CONFIG_LV_CONF_MINIMAL=y
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_LVGL=y
CONFIG_LV_MEM_CUSTOM=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LOG=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LABEL=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_BTN=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_IMG=y
CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_24=y
CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_24=y
#CONFIG_LVGL_DISPLAY_DEV_NAME="DISPLAY"

#CONFIG_ST7789V=y
CONFIG_USE_SEGGER_RTT=y

# Ble
CONFIG_BT=y
CONFIG_BT_DEBUG_LOG=y
CONFIG_BT_SMP=y
CONFIG_BT_SIGNING=y
CONFIG_BT_PERIPHERAL=y
CONFIG_BT_DIS=y
CONFIG_BT_ATT_PREPARE_COUNT=5
CONFIG_BT_BAS=y
#CONFIG_BT_HRS=y
#CONFIG_BT_IAS=y
CONFIG_BT_PRIVACY=y
CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME="Test BLE Service"
CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_APPEARANCE=833
CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME_DYNAMIC=y
CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME_MAX=65

CONFIG_BT_KEYS_OVERWRITE_OLDEST=y
CONFIG_BT_SETTINGS=y
CONFIG_FLASH=y
CONFIG_FLASH_PAGE_LAYOUT=y
CONFIG_FLASH_MAP=y
CONFIG_NVS=y
CONFIG_SETTINGS=y
```

Comment: Which version of the nRF Connect SDK did you use?
Which build target did you build for? (board name)